# Getting two line listview to inflate AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog, android-context, layout-inflater

Below is a `baseAdapter` class to inflate a two line listview into an  `alertDialog` I have done a little research to assist me with this code and now I have crossed a problem that I do not know how to solve.  the method `getLayoutInflater` at the bottom of the class has a syntax error underneath it and it says that `The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type MyAdapter`  I have also tried asking a couple of my friends but they could not help me either,  So I was just hoping somebody could help me with this error

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    final String[] listItemsFirstRow = {"item 1", "item 2"};
    final String[] listItemSecondRow = {"item 1", "item 2"};

    @Override
    public int getCount() {     
        return listItemsFirstRow.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return listItemsFirstRow[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.twolinelistview, null);
        }

        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText( listItemsFirstRow[position]);
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText( listItemSecondRow[position]);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.twolinelistview, null);
```

with

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.twolinelistview, null);
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below instead to replace the line with syntax error. Hope you find it helpful.

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.twolinelistview, null);
```